# How to fit image to browser screen

Tags: html, css

I have a `.png` format HD image of size 1MB. I want to fit this image to background . so my `css` is as follow,

```
html{
    background: url("<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/Frame_73_.png")no-repeat center center fixed ;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    babackground-size: cover;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Here image is stretching. I want exact image to fit to screen. how can I do that. can anyone help me in this pls.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the screen's aspect ratio is not the same as the picture's? Should it be clipped? From the middle or from top/bottom/left/right?

Comment: clipped means what I mean what happens .

Comment: You'll either have to stretch the image or clip it. Which do you prefer?

Comment: Just a small note your general background-size rule has a typo. It says "babackground-size".

Comment: @RyanBrewer sorry I didnt understand what you said

Comment: Check out the rule `background-size: cover;` it's not spelled right.

Comment: Just use `background-size:100% 100%` if covers not working well, and remove the `min-height/width`, put up a fiddle if you still don't have the desired look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

**Notice:** it depend on the height of your page! ( 100% **100%** )

you can try this code for set height manually:

```
background-size: 100% 900px;
```

see it on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mostafaznv/7UCkk/)

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in background-size css:

```
babackground-size: cover; // extra ba
```

This should work if you want the image to cover background with clipping:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If you want background to take up whole width and scale itself to fit if needed, use:

```
background-size:contain;
```

Comment: yes I got it . i changed it now also is not fitting wel

Comment: can you post a link so i can see?

Comment: if I give contain it just display as the original size, if it is cover its not fit well, image will stretch very large so I cant visible some content of image.

Comment: how can I send link. I am working localy in eclipse.

Comment: if your image weighs around 1MB, I'm assuming its in very high res.. my first suggestion is that you take your image into photoshop or similar program.. and reduce the size of your picture, I'd say max width of 1900px.. even less.. than save it optimized for web and try again.. let me know :)

Comment: what should be image weight?

Comment: my original image size is 1024*683 px

Comment: well.. it's gonna be a bit hard to debug this with you with out seeing anything.. but try this.. write your rules on 'body' instead of 'html', remove your 'min-height' property completely, & btw did fix the typo you had? also, what browser are you testing in?

Comment: well, if your css is right, and your image is only 1024px wide.. and you say the image is stretching too large.. that means either we're missing something, or your viewport is very small.. can you repost your css?